# Is it possible to FULLY customize a Sench Tab Panel?

Tags: mobile, sencha-touch, themes, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm considering using Sencha 2 to create an app for my website, and I have a nice looking design that I need to materialize.

I can see how to simply change the background colors of a Tab Panel with Sencha, but the design calls for a little more customization than what I have found available.

Is it possible to create a tab panel with custom attributes like the arrow at the top of this one?

[image]

If so, how can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get it for the `tabpanel`.

But that kind of arrow is possible in case for floating panel like `overlays` ..

Check out this example from Sencha Docs ..

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/overlays

Comment: THanks for the answer! Do you think maybe I could use a background image?

Comment: background image for what? tabs? panel? arrow?

Comment: sorry for the delay...i meant a background image for the entire tabbar? that way i could include the arrow in the tab bar bg image...

Comment: @johnnietheblack: Why not? This is the simplest way.